# XHR Upload Progress claims immediate completion

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, tomcat

Ok, I've tried everything I can think of and perused all the existing questions, but none of them have any actual answers.

I have an angularjs front end and java/REST backend, running on Tomcat.

I have an XMLHttpRequest and a progress event listener that looks like this:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    console.log(e.loaded);
    console.log(e.total);
}, false);
```

If I'm uploading a 100MB file, the progress event listener fires repeatedly, but reports 100% within the first second.  The xhr then returns that it's loaded roughly 30 seconds to a minute later, as would be expected.  I have tried setting different headers, using sendAsBinary() instead of send, and a number of other techniques that I cannot recall off the top of my head.  The angular app is running on localhost, the Tomcat app server acts the same way whether I use my local dev instance or a hosted dev instance.

I'm looking for any ideas I can get, whether they be Tomcat settings, code changes, or anything else.  I know that the problem is not in the java backend code itself because the progress event has stopped firing at 100% done before the file processing code even begins running.  This happens on Chrome 40/FF 35/Safari 6.